# Lorum from Emmet in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

I'm having trouble with Emmet in Atom. When I type "lorum80" in an html file, I expect Emmet to generate 80 words of Lorum Ipsum, per its [documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/lorem-ipsum/). But instead, it outputs "lorum80" as a tag

```
<lorum80></lorum80>
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To what I found there was nothing stating in Emmet that it generates lorum.

I could recommend using the package [Lorem](https://atom.io/packages/lorem) for generating this kind of text. Has plenty of options for different formats.

Comment: I just added a link to Emmet documentation for the Lorum feature